# Appengine query returning no matching index - Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, objectify

I have some entities that I wish to do an ancestor query on and filter a parameter by the ">" operator.
The entity in question inherits another object(I don't think this should matter).  Below are my entity classes:

```
@Indexed
public class ValidatedObject {

public Long timeCreated=System.currentTimeMillis();
public Long timeUpdated=System.currentTimeMillis();


public Long getTimeUpdated() {
    return timeUpdated;
}
public void setTimeUpdated(Long timeUpdated) {
    this.timeUpdated = timeUpdated;
}
public Boolean validated=false;
@Unindexed
public String validatedID;
@Unindexed
private Long validatedTime;
@Unindexed
private String creatorID;

public Long getTimeCreated() {
    return timeCreated;
}
public void setTimeCreated(Long timeCreated) {
    this.timeCreated = timeCreated;
}
public boolean isValidated() {
    return validated;
}
public void setValidated(boolean validated) {
    this.validated = validated;
}
public String getValidatedID() {
    return validatedID;
}
public void setValidatedID(String validatedID) {
    this.validatedID = validatedID;
}
public Long getValidatedTime() {
    return validatedTime;
}
public void setValidatedTime(Long validatedTime) {
    this.validatedTime = validatedTime;
}
public String getCreatorID() {
    return creatorID;
}
public void setCreatorID(String creatorID) {
    this.creatorID = creatorID;
}

}



@Cached
@Entity
public class PersonnelInfo extends ValidatedObject{

  @Id
  public String keyName; 

@Parent Key<Department> department;
private Long fdID;

@Unindexed
private String userKeyName;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
@Unindexed
private String address,city,county,state;
@Unindexed
private String cellPhone,homePhone,otherPhone;


public PersonnelInfo(){

}
public PersonnelInfo(String email){
    keyName=email;
}

@Override
public Long getTimeUpdated() {
    return timeUpdated;
}
@Override
public void setTimeUpdated(Long time) {
    timeUpdated=time;
}


}
```

My query code is as follows:

```
Query<PersonnelInfo> q = ofy.query(PersonnelInfo.class).ancestor(tmp).filter("timeUpdated >",     lastSync);
```

I am getting the "no matching index found" error everytime.  The query works fine without the filter.  Some of the entities are missing the "timeUpdated" field because I changed the schema.  There are some entities that have been created after the schema change with timeUpdated values and they are not returned.  Also I can do a GQL query on the datastore viewer like this:

select * where FROM PersonnelInfo timeUpdated > 0

and I am returned entities, which makes me believe the index is created.  What am I doing wrong here?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a multi-property index defined in your datastore-indexes.xml.  It should be added to datastore-indexes-auto.xml when you run the query in dev mode, but the result should look like this:

```
<datastore-index kind="PersonnelInfo" ancestor="true">
    <property name="timeUpdated" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Comment: yup! stickfigure to the rescue again.  Thanks man!  My query was never ran in dev mode

Comment: Little confused on when you must create a multi-property index.  For example if you do a query ofy().query(someclass).filter("time",time).filter("person",person); right?

Comment: There's a lot of discussion on this page:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries  The upshot is that you need the index when you are using multiple properties (or prop + ancestor), except that the query engine is sometimes smart enough to optimize using single-property indexes.  I believe two-property equality queries can be optimized.